# UBS cable disrupts mic input from audio jack

Tags: android, audio, microphone, smartphone, android-audiorecord

im receiving data from the microphone audio jack, every thing is fine until i connect a USB cable to the device (for power and charging needs). the mic input gets disrupted and instead of sine wave i only get noise. what is the cause of this? and what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a software issue or it could be an issue with the hardware configuration. Any time you have a device connected by both the USB charger and an audio cable there's the potential for a ground loop to develop, which can give lots of interference. If your audio signal is already quite weak this could completely mask it.

Where is the audio coming from? Where are you charging from? Do you get the same issue if it's plugged into a laptop rather than a wall charger (or the other way round)? If you're using an auxiliary input cable from a sound source, can you instead use a standalone microphone?

Comment: thanks for the replay. the audio is a sine wave that i generate and the usb cable is connected to my pc. the standalone microphone works fine.

Comment: when the USB is connected to the charger i dont get this problem

Comment: Can you clarify: If you use a stand alone microphone placed near a speaker which is outputting a sine wave while the phone is plugged into the computer, can you see the microphone signal on the phone? It sounds like the issue is due to a ground loop between the computer sound card and the USB port. There isn't an easy way to remove it in software. A ground loop isolator (a few dollars from amazon/ebay) would probably fix the problem.